# PreparedStatment not fetching data from MySql using Java Class's Method parameters

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to pass username and password from a jsp page to Authenticate Method in a Java class (LogMeIn.java), but I am getting 'false'  as a result. However when I hard code values (abc/abc) I do get 'pass' result. ie. it's successful.

Please can you advise why it's not accepting the parameters passed through jsp?

--LogMeIn.java--

```
package org.cms.model;

      import java.sql.Connection;
      import java.sql.ResultSet;
      import java.sql.SQLException;
      import java.sql.Statement;
      import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

      import javax.naming.Context;
      import javax.naming.InitialContext;
      import javax.sql.DataSource;


      public class LogMeIn {


        public boolean Authenticate( String username, String password ) {

          Connection connection = null;
           // Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            String query;
            boolean result = false;

            try {
              Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
              Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
              DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
              connection = ds.getConnection();
                //statement = connection.createStatement();

                query = "select name from account where name= ? and password = ?";

                pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);

                pst.setString(1, username);
                pst.setString(2, password);

                resultSet = pst.executeQuery();

                int count=0;

                if(resultSet.next())
                {
               count++;
                }
                if(count>0)
                {
                  result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                  result = false;
                }
            }

            catch (SQLException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
                if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            }

          return result;
        }

      }
```

---LoginServlet---

```
    package org.cms.controller;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.cms.model.LogMeIn;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      /**
       * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       */
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username;
        String password;

        username = request.getParameter("user");
        password = request.getParameter("pass");

        LogMeIn a = new LogMeIn();

        boolean result = a.Authenticate(username, password);
            System.out.println(result);
        if (result) {
          request.setAttribute("loginresult","Pass");
          RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
          dispatcher.forward(request, response);
          }
        else {
          request.setAttribute("loginresult","Failed");
          RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
          dispatcher.forward(request, response);
          }

      }

    }
```

---Login.jsp---

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  %>  
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"></link>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="validate.js"> </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate(this)" method="post" action="LoginServlet" class="form">
      <table border = "0">
      <tr align="left" valign="top">
      <td>User Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name ="user" class="inputbox"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="left" valign="top">
      <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name ="pass" class="inputbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="left" valign="top">
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" 
      value="submit" class="fb8"/></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <c:out  value="${loginresult}" > </c:out>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: What parameters _does_ JSP pass in to LogMeIn? Have you printed them out to console?

Comment: What does validate() do?

Comment: Side note: your 12 last lines before the catch block in LogMeIn could be reduced to `result = resultSet.next();`

Comment: Odds are that you need to wrap them in quotes, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks you all specially DNA! Validate() was looking at a non-existent javascript file. the issue was null parameters were being passed to servlet because of Validate() method.                      JB Nizet - thanks for your suggestion, i have made that change in my code. can you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

use setAttribute() method. This method sets the value of the attribute for the request which is retrieved later in the servlet by passing the request object through the dispatcher method. The set value of the attribute is retrieved by the getAttribute() method of the request object.

```
   http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/request-parameter.shtml

 http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/servlet/passParameters.html
```